# How to use cross-domain connections (CORS - Access Control Allow Origin) with SignalR

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, cors

Using persistent connections and an ASP.NET JavaScript client, I am trying to connect to a sub-domain not the same as the one the page was served from.

ASP.Net Page from webserver `sub1.mydomain.com` wants to connect to SignalR at `sub2.mydomain.com`. The same code works fine when connecting within the same sub-domain.

I found another post where cross-domain connections were enabled with:

```js
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

but this did not work for me.

How can I connect to SignalR in a second sub-domain using persistent connection and a JavaScript client?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need to do one of the following to make it work:

- Set up `$.connection.hub.url = 'http://subdomain.domain.com/signalr';`, pointing to your subdomain.
- Enable cross domain on the server:

  ```
  RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration()
  {
    EnableCrossDomain = true
  });
  ```

Comment: I've tried the first and third bullet, but I am using persistent connection and so the second bullet would not apply. Still fails to connect.

Comment: @codezoo For persistent connections you can also specify a url, eg. `var con = $.connection('echo'); con.url = http://my.domain.com/echo.` Specifying the full URL here: `$.connection('http://my.domain.com/echo')` should also work, although I haven't checked.

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I am currently using this method: $.connection('http://my.domain.com/echo')

Comment: I should note that when you're self-hosting signalR, the `Server` appears to add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header automatically.

Comment: @PiotrSzmyd setting the url through `$.connection('http://my.domain.com/echo')` was not enough to start the hub cross-origin. When the hub starts it gets the client _host_ when `hub.url` is not set with a host.

Comment: I get this output:
...\Global.asax.cs(17,64,17,81): error CS0117: 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration' does not contain a definition for 'EnableCrossDomain'
...\Global.asax.cs(17,13,17,91): error CS0619: 'System.Web.Routing.SignalRRouteExtensions.MapHubs(System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection, Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.HubConfiguration)' is obsolete: 'Use IAppBuilder.MapSignalR in an Owin Startup class. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320578 for more details.'

Comment: @AkiraYamamoto The way to do Cross Domain communication in SignalR 2.0 is to add an OWIN Startup class, take the `IAppBuilder` object and call `app.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableJSONP = true });`

Comment: But I still would like to use WebSockets when available, not JSONP.

Comment: For SignalR 2, [Ian Mercer's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/35067160/2747593) is correct (and doesn't require enabling JSONP).

Answer (score 14):

In the current version of SignalR, using the now separate CORS package, the API for this has changed to:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
        {
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

See [ASP.NET SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](//www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client).

Comment: You'll also need to add `using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;` (as well as install the corresponding NuGet package) if you haven't already.

Comment: Is it safe to use AllowAll? Wouldn't this mean any website could be set up to receive notifications from SignalR?

Answer (score 7):

If switching from 0.5.1 to 0.5.2, you may have had the following:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'longPolling', xdomain: true }, function () {...
```

Which can be changed to:

```
$.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }, function () {...
```

Answer (score 4):

In Signalr2, you can use the pre-release of **Microsoft.Owin.Cors**, currently **3.0.0-rc1** as of writing this: [Microsoft.Owin.Cors](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Cors/3.0.0-rc1).

More information can be found here:

- http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client
- http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20

Answer (score 1):

```
var connection = $.connection('http://somecrossdomainurl/echo')
connection.start({ transport: 'longPolling', xdomain: true });
```

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client

Answer (score 1):

What really have solved my issue was:

1 - Add this to global.asax:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration() { 
    EnableCrossDomain = true 
});
```

2- Set up the web.config of my web project to enable the cross-domain:

> ```
> <system.webServer>
>     <httpProtocol>
>         <customHeaders>
>             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
>             <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
>         </customHeaders>
>     </httpProtocol>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

3- Then I change the implementation on my html, changing the $.connection() to as follow:

> ```
> var connection = $.hubConnection('http://localhost.my:8081/signalr');
> var chatHubProxy = connection.createHubProxy('chatHub');
> ```

Versions I'm using:

- signalR-1.1.0
- jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js
- dot.net 4.0

Comment: I am using the 4 sub domains , should i have to host my hub class on each sub domains or should i have to host my complete website on all the subdomain including the web pages that i have?

Comment: RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(config); is deprecated; CORS is now enabled by default per http://weblogs.asp.net/davidfowler/signalr-0-5-1-released