# Issues with SignalR and Cross Domain requests in Chrome 27

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, cross-domain, signalr

**EDIT: This is apparently only a problem in Chrome, it works fine in FF and IE**

**Chrome version: 27.0.1453.116**

I've got a simple JS/HTML site on localhost:13371, and I'm trying to access a SignalR hub at localhost:13371.

Whenever the request is made, I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://localhost:13370/signalr/hubs/negotiate?_=1372338722032`. Origin `http://localhost:13371` is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

## What I've tried already:

- Enabling Cross-Domain on SignalR on `Application_Start`:

  ```
  RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });
  ```
- Enabling Cross-Domain in the Web.Config of the SignalR server:

  ```
  <system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
       <customHeaders>
         <clear />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
       </customHeaders>
     </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
  ```
- Setting up the connection url on signalr's hub in JavaScript:

  ```
  $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:13370/signalr/hubs';
  ```
- Enabling CORS in jQuery:

  ```
  $.support.cors = true;
  ```
- Setting response header manually in `Application_BeginRequest`:

  ```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
      {
          //These headers are handling the "pre-flight" OPTIONS call sent by the browser
          HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
          HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
          HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
          HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
      }
  }
  ```

### None of the above, nor any combination of the above has worked.

Additional information:

- Both sites are running in IIS on Windows 7
- The SignalR site is running on port 13370 as part of a MVC 4 site under .NET 4.0.
- The JS/HTML site is a simple webserver on port 13371, no managed code at all.
- The SignalR site will definitely respond to direct requests from the browser for the resource in question.
- SignalR version is 1.1.2

Comment: Did you try reading http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#establishconnection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## EDIT: I've found two solutions for this now...

### Method 1. get rid of crap you probably don't need:

As I found in this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467373/signalr-1-0-1-cross-domain-request-cors-with-chrome), basically nearly everything I had added in my listing of "things I've tried" above were unnecessary.  Steps to fix:

1. Remove everything I've listed that I've tried above. That means no custom headers specified at all in the Web.Config or elsewhere like the Global.asax, no custom jquery settings, etc.
2. .. except for `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(new HubConfiguration { EnableCrossDomain = true });` In the `Application_Start`.
3. Also you still need to set the `$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:13370/signalr/hubs';`

... that's it.  **this is probably the best solution and the one I ended up using.**

### Method 2. use jsonp if you're still having problems in Chrome:

If you're still having problems like this in Chrome you can use jsonp to get that negotiate script to download properly... adding the following to my JavaScript hub start solved the issue:

```
//detect chrome
var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

//set the connection url.
$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:13370/signalr/hubs';

//use jsonp if chrome
$.connection.hub.start({
    jsonp: isChrome
});
```

There is probably a better way to do this that tests the browser capabilities and sets jsonp accordingly... looking at the user agent feels dirty as hell... but this solved my problem in the interim. I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: I have done the same thing as in Method 1 above and, while I am not getting any errors, my client refuses to connect to my SignalR hub. It gets to the step where it tries to negotiate with the hub and is unable to establish connection because the ProtocolVersion of the result object  (from when Ajax tries to establish the connection) is different from the clientProtocol property of the connection. The former is 1.4 and the latter 1.5. because of that the connection is refused. None of the suggestion in this thread have worked for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Put this method on Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    var referrer = Request.UrlReferrer;
    if (Context.Request.Path.Contains("signalr/") && referrer != null)
    {
        Context.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", referrer.Scheme + "://" + referrer.Authority);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in my MVC6 SignarR server. 
Just installed `Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors` in **Package Manager Console** & added  `app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)` in Startup.cs.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the docs, but never do this:

$.support.cors = true;

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me is following.

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var config = new HubConfiguration
        {
            EnableCrossDomain = true
        };
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(config);
    }
    protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Context.Request.Path.Contains("signalr/"))
        {
            this.Context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "accept,origin,authorization,content-type");
        }
    }
```