# SignalR not working with DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

We have a delegating-handler that catches requests with a certain url prefix, and then reroutes them behind the firewall with the fed auth cookie attached...

This is working for our WebApi layer, but SingalR is firing off requests on its own while it is trying to connect that doesn't follow the pattern... I can't figure out how to force it to use the proper url prefix.

This is the url that is generated from the post request when it is trying to do long-polling: https://localhost:44330/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&

See that it hasn't put the '/qsixlsignalr' into the url, which my delegating handler will be looking for.

```
var signalRBaseURL = "/qsixlsignalr"

$(function () {

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467373/signalr-1-0-1-cross-domain-request-cors-with-chrome
        $.support.cors = false;         

        var connection = $.hubConnection(signalRBaseURL);
        var myHub = connection.createHubProxy('xlHub');

        myHub.on('notify', function (message) {

            alertsViewModel.refreshActiveCount(localStorage.getItem(PROJECT_ID));

            if (window.location.pathname == '/' || window.location.pathname == '') {
                alertsViewModel.refresh(localStorage.getItem(PROJECT_ID));
            }

            toastr.success(message);

        });         

        connection.disconnected(function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                connection.start();
            }, 3000); 
        });

        connection.logging = true;
        connection.start();         

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you need to tell SignalR explicitly that you don't want to use the the default url

```
  var connection = $.hubConnection(signalRBaseURL, { useDefaultPath: false });
```