# Not getting distributed/disparate Angular site to talk to SignalR in WebAPI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I very new to SignalR and I am trying to integrate it with an AngularJS site and WebAPI. I followed greate [this](http://www.squarewidget.com/signalr-mvc-angular-web-api) example to begin with. However, as I mentioned, the website I am working on will live on a different server to the WebAPI project.

In my dev environment I have set up a local site for Angular, hosted in IIS on localhost:60000/127.0.0.1:60000 and the WebAPI lives on localhost:31374 (in VS2013, using IIS Express.) This is to simulate the 2 different servers the projects will live on.

In my Angular project I am trying to connect to the SignalR hub by doing the following:

```
var connection = $.hubConnection();

$.connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:31374/signalr";

//$.connection.url = "/signalr";
//$.conenction.baseUrl = "http://localhost:31374";

this.proxy = connection.createHubProxy('foos');

console.clear();
// start connection
console.log(connection);
connection.start();

this.proxy.on('newFoo', function (data) {
    $rootScope.$emit("newFoo", data);
});
```

The result in the console looks like this:

[image: Console result when trying to connect to signalr]

In my code you can see in that I am trying to set the hub url (and in the comments just below it, that I have tried to set the connection object's properties manually.) However, in the screenshot you can see that neither the URL or the baseURL is what I set it to be, in fact the baseURL still points back to the Angular site on http://127.0.0.1:60000/, in stead of http://localhost:31374/.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're setting the hub.url on $.connection instead of your local connection variable. Did you mean `connection.hub.url = "http://localhost:31374/signalr"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set up looks a little off. Specifically, perhaps your `connection.start()` call is not correct. I've done this in Angular with a cross domain server with the following setup which works fine

```
var proxy;

$(function () {

    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:31374/signalr';

    $.connection.hub.start({ xdomain: true })
        .done(function () { 
            console.log('Connected. connectionId : ' + $.connection.hub.id); 
        })
        .fail(function () {
            console.log('Could not connect!');
        });

    proxy = $.connection.yourServerHubName;

    proxy.client.yourClientHubMethod = function () {
        // your client hub functions
    };
});
```

Also be sure to check you are loading the proper generated .js file in your HTML

```
<script src="//localhost:31374/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Sal, that works. I am curious though - I noticed the `xdomain`, is that what makes the biggest difference?

Comment: @MrThursday my guess in your situation is no. I really think it was the way you had the client connection `.start` set up. However I included that value as a fallback in case you were using an older version of signalr see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9984534/1464112) for some more details. Glad it works for you regardless