# signalR CORS error: Access-Control-Allow-Origin on local instances

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, signalr

When I am trying to connect to signalR (Asp.Net WebApi) through a seperate app (angular4) all locally, I get the  following error:

> http://127.0.0.1:50840/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22apihub%22%7D%5D&_=1503591726722.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:61679' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

What was done [here](https://forums.asp.net/t/2033309.aspx?Calling%20SignalR%20hub%20from%20other%20domain%20via%20CORS) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984534/how-to-use-cross-domain-connections-cors-access-control-allow-origin-with-si) by doing the following:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
        map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); //TODO: FIX THIS
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration()
        {
        };
        map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
}
```

But that still does not seem to work - any ideas?  The Configuration gets hit on app startup.  It seems simple, what am I missing?  Thank you.

Comment: Did you install the nugget `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`...if not, then follow these instructions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619656/enable-cors-in-web-api-2#27360022

Comment: No, but I did the more recent version which is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api